# Verifying Android odex-file programmatically

Tags: android, caching, dalvik

Is it possible to verify the integrity/checksum of the system-generated odex-file programmatically?

I wonder how to detect, if an attacker on a rooted Android phone installs his own version of the odex file for an application.

Comment: Probably only by repeating the optimization process against the exact same system using a trusted installer or equivalent.  You'd need to get the same output from something you trust.

Comment: You were right, I misread the question, sorry! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assumption is that, if an attacker is able to replace a .odex file, they have sufficient permission to do any number of other things.

The build-generated odex files live in a protected directory on /system, which is mounted read-only.  Anyone able to modify those files could simply hack the VM or replace major parts of the system.

The installd-generated odex files live in /data/dalvik-cache, and are protected by filesystem permissions.  Anyone with permission to modify a .odex file would be able to do all sorts of things, like reinstall applications while you're not looking.  This would be a better approach for an attacker, since it would survive an OTA update (which causes a re-dexopt).

Modifying optimized DEX data in place is doable but kind of a pain.  The advantage of doing so over replacing an app is that it's more subtle -- to reinstall an app you either need the original signing key, or hope that the user doesn't realize they're now running an app with the same name but a different signer.

So, the .odex file has a checksum you can look at in case you doubt the integrity of the filesystem, but no provision to check for tampering other than re-executing dexopt and comparing before & after.

General info about dexopt and odex is available in the Android sources in [dalvik/docs/dexopt.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/docs/dexopt.html); a nicely formatted version is [available here](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/dexopt.html).

**Edit:** I should mention that the DEX and ODEX files do have checksums stored in the file headers.  These are usually ignored because, for performance reasons, you don't want to go scanning through the entire file every time you launch an app.  You can enable mandatory checksum verification by setting the `dalvik.vm.check-dex-sum` property to `true` (or pass `-Xchecksum` on the command line).

The checksums are intended to detect file corruption, not deliberate alterations.  (You can use `dexdump -c` to scan manually.)  Someone tampering with the file could just recompute a valid checksum and store it, so you'd need to save a known good copy elsewhere.  And you'd want to use SHA1 or similar rather than adler32 to make it harder to manipulate the binary to get the same checksum value.

Comment: Nitpick, but aren't the .odex files for 3rd party apps on /data - ie, permission protected, but not on a write-protected filesystem?   Wherever they are has to be writable by the system during app installation.  Bundled apps for which only odexes are provided are on /system though.

Comment: Yes -- perhaps I interpreted the question too narrowly.  I expanded the answer.

Comment: fadden, I partly agree with the assumption that if an attacker is able to modify the odex files, he is able to do virtually anything. However there is a practical aspect involved. Let's say the attacker managed to edit the odex file for a bank app in such a way that the user creedentials are captured, but otherwise the app behaves as usual. This attack will not be possible, if the app still contains runtime checks for odex/apk-integrity (due to character limit see my next comment).

Comment: I am well aware that the attacker could also try to locate the checks in the code and disable them, but still this complicates matters for him. For example if the check is performed from native code. I image the app could natively invoke the static method DexFile.isDexOptNeeded(). Any ideas how good this check (isDexOptNeeded) is?

Comment: What you're describing is equivalent to copy protection or anti-cheat tamper proofing that some games use.  It becomes a race between the app dev and the malware dev.  You can make it arbitrarily difficult but you can't make it impossible once you allow malware to modify files in dalvik-cache.  `isDexOptNeeded` doesn't scan the whole DEX file; it just examines the dependency lists to see if something is out of date.  You could manually invoke dexopt, sending the output to a temp file, and then checksum or binary-diff the files to look for discrepancies  (...assuming dexopt wasn't compromised).

Comment: (Added a link to the dexopt docs, which are slightly inaccurate at this point but provide useful background.)

Comment: fadden, do you have some more details about the implementation of isDexOptNeeded? I mean links, articles etc.?

Comment: Just the sources, in e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/.  isDexOptNeeded() is a native method implemented inside the VM.  It calls dvmDexCacheStatus(), which finds the odex file that matches the dex file in question, and calls dvmCheckOptHeaderAndDependencies().  That loads the BOOTCLASSPATH dependency info out of the odex file and compares it against the current bootstrap DEX files.

Comment: fadden, thank you for pointing me at the Dalvik-source. It seems correct that isDexOptNeeded() invokes dvmDexCacheStatus() and eventually dvmCheckOptHeaderAndDependencies() (through dvmOpenCachedDexFile). However it seems that a timestamp and a CRC is also checked, which I beleave will detect an altered odex file. Do you agree?

Comment: I believe you're referring to the comparison on CRC and timestamp that happens for non-build-generated ODEX files.  This is how the system determines that the DEX in the APK does not match the ODEX in /data/dalvik-cache.  dexopt takes the timestamp (from the APK) and CRC (of classes.dex) and stores them in the ODEX; if they don't match later on, we assume the DEX has been updated.  To detect an altered ODEX file, you'd need the checksum to be computed *on the ODEX* rather than the original DEX.  (I will add a note about -Xcheckdexsum to the answer, since it's related.)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But I could image two ways of alter the odex. One would be to repack the apk with a changed classes.dex and let dexopt generate the odex. When done replace the repacked apk with the original apk, but still leaving the new odex in /data/dalvik-cache. In this case the CRC would be changed, I guess. This is the situation, I would like to detect with DexFile.isDexOptNeeded (the second way of altering the odex is by hand, which I believe is a big challenge, hence I can live with that). Does this make sense?

Comment: If the checksum and date stamp don't match, Dalvik will think the cached odex file is out of date, and refuse to start (it will want to re-dexopt the file, but won't have permission to modify the file).  Follow dvmJarFileOpen() to dvmOpenCachedDexFile(), which also calls dvmCheckOptHeaderAndDependencies().  So doing it manually isn't useful.  Besides, an attacker could (1) replace dex, (2) dexopt, (3) restore dex, (4) modify odex dependency set to have the date+checksum from the original dex.  The checksums match each other and are correct for the file contents.

Comment: So your point is that the DexFile.isDexOptNeeded only make sense, if it invoked on another app apk and never make sense, if it is invoked on its own corresponding apk, since it the latter case it app will never have been started in the first place? This is also my experience, since I tried this scenario, and the app did not start. Would it be a workable approach to (1) find the odex file (2) calculate the CRC (3) somehow get the correct CRC similar to dexGetZipEntryCrc32 (4) compare ? Thank you fadden, you have brought me a lot of insight into the innter details.

Comment: First part: yes.  Second part: the tricky bit is part (3).  You need to have the known-correct checksum value stored somewhere, and a sophisticated attacker could tamper with that as well.  A rigorous system would (1) verify the signature on the APK, (2) re-generate the odex, (3) launch; but that's going to hurt app startup times.  Another thing to ponder: odex files are mmap()ed, so you could conceivably modify it in place while the app executes... but that's a whole other topic.

Comment: Consider the attack: 1) hacker installs an APK app. 2) hacker alters the generated odex file (either by directly altering the odex or by inserting correct checksum into a dexopt-created version). What is the Android defence mechanism against this attack? Does Android only rely on directory permissions? Do you think, it is a realistic attack?

Comment: The Android restricted privilege setup is the primary line of defense.  If the device is rooted, and malware can take advantage of it, there's not much to prevent installation and mutation of malware.  You could counter it with something like a virus scanner.

Comment: fadden, I agree, but in practice I am happy just to set obstacles for an attacker, such that he attacks another app. Just for experiments I would like to generate the odex file myself. Do you have some documentations on invoking dexopt manually? (command line arguments, syntax etc.). I guess that there is no API call to it (DexFile.LoadDex does not seem to help here).

Comment: There are multiple ways to invoke dexopt.  I think the easiest is the one that the build system uses (`--preopt`).  The entry point is in `dalvik/vm/dexopt/OptMain.c[pp]`; see the comment above `preopt()` for details, and dex-preopt script for an example (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/tools/dex-preopt).  If you're invoking it from a VM process you can use one of the other variations; look around in OptMain for details on each.